# Does the bid price of a stock change depending on which brokerage I am using?

Tags: stock-exchanges, broker

If I have an account with two separate discount brokerages and they have different market makers on NASDAQ, is it possible that they will give me different quotes? Will the bid price of brokerage #1 will be different from bid price of brokerage #2?

My guess is yes. On the NYSE, where there is a specialist and not a market maker, does the above question still have the same answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They could have different quotes as there are more than a few pieces here.  Are you talking a Real Time Level II quote or just a delayed quote?  Delayed quotes could vary as different companies would be using different time points in their data.  You aren't specifying exactly what kind of quote from which system are you using here.

The key to this question is how much of a pinpoint answer do you want and how prepared are you to pay for that kind of access to the automated trades happening?  Remember that there could well be more than a few trades happening each millisecond and thus latency is something to be very careful here, regardless of the exchange as long as we are talking about first-world stock exchanges where there are various automated systems being used for trading.

---

Different market makers is just a possible piece of the equation here.  One could have the same market maker but if the timings are different,e.g. if one quote is at 2:30:30 and the other is at 2:30:29 there could be a difference given all the trades processed within that second, thus the question is how well can you get that split second total view of bids and asks for a stock.  You want to get all the outstanding orders which could be a non-trivial task.

Comment: Thank you. I am asking if i am using level 2 quotes on both brokerage websites, can the price vary because they use different market makers?